# Why can I *only* access an object property inside setInterval?

Tags: javascript, ajax, object, setinterval

Here's the setup. In a previous question, I found out that I could pass an object property via state in a child component, then grab that object property with componentDidUpdate. In this case, both the state and prop are called arrival.

Here's the basic code...

```
export default class App extends Component {
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        arrival: {}
    }
}

axiosFunc = () => {
    axios.get('https://api.warframestat.us/pc').then(results => {
        this.setState({
            arrival: results.data.voidTrader.activation,
        });
        setTimeout(this.axiosFunc,1000 * 60);
    })
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.axiosFunc();
}

}
```

Now in a child component, I can't access the arrival prop like this...

```
componentDidMount(){
console.log(this.props.arrival)
}
```

But I can put it in componentDidUpdate. I also realized that I can put it in a setInterval, then run that setInterval in componentDidMount.

```
componentDidMount() {

this.intervalFunc = setInterval(() => {
console.log(this.props.arrival);
}
  , 1000);
```

}

Why can I access this.props.arrival after putting it inside setInterval, but not outside of it?

Comment: the first time the function inside `setInterval` gets called is after 1000ms. maybe `props` has values then, and not before that.

Comment: Your arrival property is set in the callback of a promise. The promise will have resolved by the time your first Interval runs, but not will not have resolved during any code run syncronously during page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be completely wrong, however: I believe your issue is based upon the fact that a React child cannot tell whether its' props have updated or not, which results in the component not re-rendering (and therefore inheriting the props).
Using `setInterval` does propmt the component to update every x amount of seconds, however.
Try setting the props as state in your child component using `componentDidUpdate` like below and see if it works

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps !== this.props) {
    this.setState({arrival: this.props.arrival});
  }
}
```